# Isomorphism classes of vector bundles (notation)

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, notation

Could someone please tell me what the notation $H_1\backslash G/H_2$ means? Here, $G$ is a group and $H_1,H_2\subset G$ are subgroups.

To give some context, I have seen a result which states that isomorphism classes of vector bundles of rank $n$ over $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ are in bijective correspondence with $\operatorname{GL}_n(k[T])\backslash \operatorname{GL}_n(k[T^{\pm 1}])/\operatorname{GL}_n(k[T^{-1}])$

Comment: There is a notion of double cosets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_coset.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H_1, H_2 \subseteq G$ be subgroups and let $H_1$ act from the left and $H_2$ act from the right on $G$. Then, we obtain so-called *double cosets* $$H_1 g H_2 = \{h_1 g h_2 : h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H_2 \}$$ for $g \in G$. The set of all such double cosets is denoted by $H_1 \backslash G / H_2$.

One possible reference is Neukirch, *Algebraic Number Theory*, §1.9.